# Nested Objects in Form Not Updating

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.1, playframework-2.2

I'm having trouble with my form when trying to update the values of the NUTRITION table.  The editing form works fine for anything involving just the ITEM, but not nested objects (NUTRITION).  The fill works fine though for the NUTRITION, and the form receives the data.  However when I repopulate the form, it shows zero's for the fill values after.

**VIEW / EDIT FORM**

```
@(id: Long, itemForm: Form[Item])

@import helper._

@implicitFieldConstructor = @{ FieldConstructor(twitterBootstrapInput.render) } 

@main {
    <div class="panel panel-primary" style="font-family: Crumble;font-weight:bold">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h1 class="panel-title">Edit Item</h1>
            </div>

        @form(routes.Admin.update(id)) {
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Item Information</legend>

                @inputText(itemForm("name"), '_label -> "Item name")
                @inputText(itemForm("description"), '_label -> "Item description")
                @inputText(itemForm("image_url"), '_label -> "Image URL")
                @inputText(itemForm("nutrition.serving_size"), '_label -> "Serving Size (G)")
                @inputText(itemForm("nutrition.calories"), '_label -> "Calories")
                @inputText(itemForm("nutrition.calories_fat"), '_label -> "Calories From Fat")
                @inputText(itemForm("nutrition.total_fat"), '_label -> "Total Fat (G)")
                @inputText(itemForm("nutrition.sat_fat"), '_label -> "Saturated Fat")
                @inputText(itemForm("nutrition.trans_fat"), '_label -> "Trans Fatty Acids (G)")
                @inputText(itemForm("nutrition.cholesterol"), '_label -> "Cholesterol (MG)")
                @inputText(itemForm("nutrition.sodium"), '_label -> "Sodium (MG)")
                @inputText(itemForm("nutrition.carbs"), '_label -> "Carbohydrates (G)")
                @inputText(itemForm("nutrition.fiber"), '_label -> "Dietary Fiber (G)")
                @inputText(itemForm("nutrition.sugar"), '_label -> "Sugars (G)")
                @inputText(itemForm("nutrition.protein"), '_label -> "Protein (G)")
                @inputText(itemForm("nutrition.vitamin_c"), '_label -> "Vitamin C (%DV)")
                @inputText(itemForm("nutrition.calcium"), '_label -> "Calcium (%DV)")
                @inputText(itemForm("nutrition.iron"), '_label -> "Iron (%DV)")

                @select(
                    itemForm("category.id"), 
                    options(Category.options), 
                    '_label -> "Category", '_default -> "-- Choose a category --",
                    '_showConstraints -> false
                )
            </fieldset>

        <div class="footer">
            <div class="form-actions">
                <input type="submit" value="Save this item" class="btn btn-primary"> or 
                <a href="@routes.Admin.adminItems()" class="btn">Cancel</a> 
            </div>
        }
        </div>
        @form(routes.Admin.delete(id), 'class -> "topRight") {
            <input style="margin-right:25px;margin-top:100px" type="submit" value="Delete this item" class="btn btn-danger">
        }
    </div>     
}
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
 public static Result edit(Long id) {
            Form<Item> itemForm = form(Item.class).fill(Item.find.byId(id));

            return ok(editItemForm.render(id, itemForm));
        }

        public static Result update(Long id) {
            Form<Item> itemForm = form(Item.class).bindFromRequest();
            if(itemForm.hasErrors()) {
                return badRequest(editItemForm.render(id, itemForm));
            }
            itemForm.get().update(id);
            flash("success", "item " + itemForm.get().name + " has been updated");
            return GO_ADMIN;
        }

        public static Result create() {
            Form<Item> itemForm = form(Item.class);
            return ok(
                createItemForm.render(itemForm)
            );
        }

        public static Result save() {
            Form<Item> itemForm = form(Item.class).bindFromRequest();
            if(itemForm.hasErrors()) {
                return badRequest(createItemForm.render(itemForm));
            }
            itemForm.get().save();

            flash("success", "item " + itemForm.get().name + " has been created");
            return GO_ADMIN;
        }
```

**PRINT OUT**

```
Form Information View for Edit:
Some(models.Item@a)
{}

Form Information Updated:
Some(models.Item@28ddd490)
{nutrition.trans_fat=0.0, nutrition.carbs=1, category.id=3, nutrition.sat_fat=1.
5, nutrition.sugar=0, nutrition.serving_size=55, nutrition.sodium=220, nutrition
.total_fat=10.0, nutrition.vitamin_c=0, image_url=images/items/subs/bacon_egg_ch
eese.jpg, nutrition.cholesterol=10, description=Start the day with sizzling Beec
hwoodΓÇá Smoked Back Bacon, free range egg omelette and melted cheese.ΓÇÖ., nutr
ition.calcium=0, name=Bacon, Egg and Cheese, nutrition.calories=100, nutrition.p
rotein=0, nutrition.calories_fat=90, nutrition.iron=0, nutrition.fiber=0}

Form Information View for Edit:
Some(models.Item@a)
{}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ended up solving my problem by adding a separate form for nutrition.  Here's the code below.

```
<legend>Item Information</legend>
                @inputText(itemForm("name"), '_label -> "Item name")
                @inputText(itemForm("description"), '_label -> "Item description")
                @inputText(itemForm("image_url"), '_label -> "Image URL")

                @select(
                    itemForm("category.id"), 
                    options(Category.options), 
                    '_label -> "Category", '_default -> "-- Choose a category --",
                    '_showConstraints -> false
                )

                <legend>Florida Nutrition Information</legend>
                @inputText(nutritionFormFlorida("serving_size"), '_label -> "Serving Size (G)")
                @inputText(nutritionFormFlorida("calories"), '_label -> "Calories")
                @inputText(nutritionFormFlorida("calories_fat"), '_label -> "Calories From Fat")
                @inputText(nutritionFormFlorida("total_fat"), '_label -> "Total Fat (G)")
                @inputText(nutritionFormFlorida("sat_fat"), '_label -> "Saturated Fat")
                @inputText(nutritionFormFlorida("trans_fat"), '_label -> "Trans Fatty Acids (G)")
                @inputText(nutritionFormFlorida("cholesterol"), '_label -> "Cholesterol (MG)")
                @inputText(nutritionFormFlorida("sodium"), '_label -> "Sodium (MG)")
                @inputText(nutritionFormFlorida("carbs"), '_label -> "Carbohydrates (G)")
                @inputText(nutritionFormFlorida("fiber"), '_label -> "Dietary Fiber (G)")
                @inputText(nutritionFormFlorida("sugar"), '_label -> "Sugars (G)")
                @inputText(nutritionFormFlorida("protein"), '_label -> "Protein (G)")
                @inputText(nutritionFormFlorida("vitamin_c"), '_label -> "Vitamin C (%DV)")
                @inputText(nutritionFormFlorida("calcium"), '_label -> "Calcium (%DV)")
                @inputText(nutritionFormFlorida("iron"), '_label -> "Iron (%DV)")
```